# XMLHttpRequest cannot load in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I am learning from this [site](http://www.geeks.gallery/angularjs-how-to-get-data-like-jquery-ajax-from-database-using-php/).

I use this for an Android application to fetch the PHP data and show the application.

When I start the web service in AngularJS, Google Chrome gives this error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/JsonReturn.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>function GetUsers($scope, $http) {
    // this is where the JSON from api.php is consumed
    $http.get('http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/JsonReturn.php').
        success(function(data) {
            // here the data from the api is assigned to a variable named users
            $scope.users = data;
        });
}</script>
```

Then I set the  HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="GetUsers">

<table>
<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="user in users"><td>{{user.id}}</td><td>{{ user.name }}</td><td>{{user.email}}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

</div>
```

I tried all the possible solutions posted, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue in my code.

Comment: I think the error is pretty much self explanatory  No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. **Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be in your header**

Comment: i am add this but not working

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to make a cross domain request using XMLHttpRequest. For that to work, the web server responding to the request needs to have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header set to `*`.

Comment: Add this  `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in your JsonReturn.php

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, serve the Angular page from the same server than hosting your API. Then you don't have a cross-domain request.